# Dynamic Chunk Loading Error in React Projects Using Webpack Module Federation

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm working with two React projects (Host and Remote1) using Create React App (CRA) and Webpack Module Federation, but I'm encountering a chunk loading error. Both projects are configured with customize-cra and react-app-rewired for custom configuration. The Host exposes two modules (AuthProvider and preventCSSCollision), and Remote1 is set to only share itself.

**Issue:**

Loading a chunk from the standalone Remote1 component throws an error, while it works fine within the Host. The error message is related to loading a specific chunk file (e.g., vendors-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_api_js-node_modules_css-loader_dist_runtime_sour-d924d0.chunk.js).

**Attempts:**

Setting config.output.publicPath = '/' ensures the Host application works correctly, but standalone Remote applications throw errors.
Setting config.output.publicPath = 'auto' allows sub-routes of the remote component on the Host to function, but refreshing these pages results in failures.
Attempts to set config.output.publicPath dynamically using webpack_public_path = window.location.origin + '/' have been unsuccessful.
I've tried adding a static  tag in the head section of Remote1's HTML file, but it didn't resolve the issue and might affect internal URL handling.

**Expected Behavior:**

Host and Remote1 should load standalone without errors.
Browsing and refreshing Remote1 application sub-routes on the Host should work seamlessly.
Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

**Git Repo demostrates the problem:**

Git Repo : https://github.com/CuriousDevX/dynamic-wmf-demo